# Sharedobject don't remember data?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, shared-objects

I have this code for sharedobject:

```
var mySharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("republicofcode");
mySharedObject.data.clientID = my_vars.clientID;
mySharedObject.data.question = my_vars.question;
mySharedObject.data.answer = my_vars.answer;   
mySharedObject.flush();
```

Next time when I try this code:

```
var mySharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("republicofcode");
```

Variable mySharedObject.data.clientID is undefined. I don't know why sharedobject don't remember data?

Comment: Obligatory stupid question: are you sure `my_vars.clientID` was anything other than undefined to begin with?

Comment: Offcourse it is, I didn't write all code.

Comment: Is it the same swf? Running in the same domain?

Comment: It is, it is local xerte project, I try from browser to open and run, same result.

Comment: if you clearing cache in new browsers they will automaticaly delete `flash coockies` in this case sharedObject data.

Comment: I am not clearing cookies from browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try just a basic .fla to test the SharedObject functionality?

```
import flash.net.SharedObject;

var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal('so');

// Run once, then comment out this next line and run again.
so.data.me = 'your special data';

trace( so.data.me );
```

At least we can verify if this is working or not.

Comment: This is working, but when I refresh web page, so.data.me will be undefined.